# How to set and get the value of an loading circle @keyframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the value of the opening circle.

That means that on the first start, let's say the opening space is pointing to the bottom, then when the search completes. It should hide and appear next time when someone want to search for something on the same opening position. "in our case now, pointing to the bottom and not starting at initial value, pointing to the top"

I know that CSS cannot remember things, so it should be done with JavaScript.

It has to be IE 10 compatible.

[image]

The blue circle opening position should be saved for the next search

```
.i-map-loading {
    display: none;
    color: #0067b1;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 3000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where are you stuck? Where is your JS? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, you should show what you've tried. As the question stands, you've included very little information to help you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out ->

you just switch classes in css.

1) First of all create 2 classes in your css file :

```
.map-loading {

    color: #0067b1;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 3000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.map-loading-continue {
    animation-play-state: running;
    visibility: visible;
}

.map-loading-paused {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then you toggle your animation in your js file and switch classes everytime you need.
This is how you can pause a keyframe and make it "disapear" and appear back at the same frame.

in the function where it should animate : just add this

```
that.element.find('.map-loading').removeClass("map-loading-paused").addClass("map-loading-continue");
```

in the function where it should pause and disapear :

```
that.element.find('.map-loading').removeClass("map-loading-continue").addClass("map-loading-paused");
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS does remember things, and you have the ability to [pause your animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) from CSS directly:

```css
.i-map-loading {
  /* I borrow the stylings from Temani's answer */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-left-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 3000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  /* by default paused */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
:checked ~ .i-map-loading {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check">toggle animation</label><br>

<div class="i-map-loading"></div>
```

However, it will remember things **only for as long as your elements are in the CSSOM**, and setting `display: none;` will remove your element and all its children from there.

So you need an other way to hide your element:

```css
.i-map-loading {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-left-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 3000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  /* by default hidden, but not with display:none */
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute; /* if you need it to be removed from the page flow */
  /* by default paused */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
:checked ~ .i-map-loading {
  visibility: visible;
  position: static;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check">toggle animation</label><br>

<div class="i-map-loading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to read the value of the current angle and later you convert it to a delay so that the element will start on that angle.

Here is an exemple. When you click the button the second element will start its rotation at the same position of the first one:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var r = $('.current').css('transform');

  var a = r.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',')[0];
  var b = r.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',')[1];
  var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
  if (angle < 0)
    angle += 360;
  var delay = -5 * (angle / 360);

  $('.new').css('animation-delay', delay + 's');
  $('.new').css('animation-name', 'spin');

})
```

```css
.i-map-loading {
  color: #0067b1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-left-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red) center/20px 2px no-repeat;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="i-map-loading current"></div>
<div class="i-map-loading new" style="animation-name:none;"></div>
<br>
<button>Start</button>
```